# Keeping only the first occurrences of a data in column on a given date without removing other occurrences in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to pandas so bear with me.
I have 1 min interval wise data time frame for few years. Each row have a `Long signal` column . My index for data frame is date time column.

[image: Data Frame]

For simplicity let's take only two days data.

```
                        Long Signal
    Date 

2008-01-01 09:55        0
2008-01-01 09:56        1
2008-01-01 09:57        0
...............
2008-01-01 03:28        0
2008-01-01 03:29        1
2008-01-01 03:30        1
2008-01-02 09:55        0
2008-01-02 09:56        0
2008-01-02 09:57        1
...............
2008-01-02 03:28        0
2008-01-02 03:29        1
2008-01-02 03:30        1
```

I'm trying to convert this into data frame as below,

```
                       Long Signal
    Date 

2008-01-01 09:55        0
2008-01-01 09:56        1
2008-01-01 09:57        0
...............
2008-01-01 03:28        0
2008-01-01 03:29        0
2008-01-01 03:30        0
2008-01-02 09:55        0
2008-01-02 09:56        0
2008-01-02 09:57        1
...............
2008-01-02 03:28        0
2008-01-02 03:29        0
2008-01-02 03:30        0
```

That is I just wanna keep only the first occurrence of `Long signal` and fill with 0 for remaining occurrences on same day. That is for on any given day `Long signal` will have max only one occurrence of value 1.  Tried `drop_duplicate` but no luck. I would appreciate any help.

Edit 1 :

I want to keep the time information at which the first `Long signal` is 1. In my case for the day `2008-01-01` it is `09:56`  and for the `2008-01-02` it is `09:57` . In other words I want my data to be in 1 min time interval itself while keeping data only for the first occurrence of  value `1` in `Long signal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep only the first occurence of `Long Signal` and fill with 0 the remaining ones, you can use a combination of `loc`, `groupby` with `dt.day`, and `idxmax()`.

The `idxmax()` function is used to get the row label of the maximum value and if multiple values equal the maximum (i.e in your case 1) , the first row label with that value is returned, so it is perfect for your needs.

To illustrate:

```
df['Long Signal'] = df['Long Signal'].loc[df.groupby([df.Date.dt.day])['Long Signal'].idxmax()]
df['Long Signal'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Will get back:

```
Out[134]: 

                  Date  Long Signal
0  2008-01-01 09:55:00          0.0
1  2008-01-01 09:56:00          1.0
2  2008-01-01 09:57:00          0.0
3  2008-01-01 03:28:00          0.0
4  2008-01-01 03:29:00          0.0
5  2008-01-01 03:30:00          0.0
6  2008-01-02 09:55:00          0.0
7  2008-01-02 09:56:00          0.0
8  2008-01-02 09:57:00          1.0
9  2008-01-02 03:28:00          0.0
10 2008-01-02 03:29:00          0.0
11 2008-01-02 03:30:00          0.0
```

To keep the time information at which the first Long signal is 1, you can simply use:

```
df.loc[df['Long Signal']==1]['Date']

1   2008-01-01 09:56:00
8   2008-01-02 09:57:00
```

But I can't be 100% sure this is what you need for the 2nd part as it is not demonstrated in your desired output.

Comment: Excellent man. This works perfectly. I wish I could upvote twice. Thank you for your help.